# Таймер на 1 час в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Привет!
Помогите создать таймер на 1 час в юнити;
нужно что бы через каждый час происходило действие.

```
int aTimer = Time.deltaTime; 
if(aTimer >= 3600){//выполняем действие и обнуляем таймер aTimer =0;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float aTimer=3600f;
void Update()
{
 if(aTimer <=0f)
 {
  //действие
  aTimer =3600f;
 }
 else aTimer -= Time.deltaTime;//Time.unscaledDeltaTime
}
```

или

```
void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(OneHour());
    }

    IEnumerator OneHour()
    {
        YieldInstruction yi = new WaitForSeconds(3600f);
        while (true)
        {
            yield return yi;
            //действие
        }
    }
```

Comment: Очень простой вариант спасибо большое, у меня не получалось(